# Can not create a variable from SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables

I have a MySQL database which i am taking some information and package them in a variable. Few variables already declared by me, but on the last one I have a problem.

The problem is `Standort_ID` I have added the others cause on them the code is working.

I am taking these columns from MySQL:

```
hardware.instanzname AS 'Instanzname', 
hardware.Standort AS 'Standort_ID',
```

Now I am hiding the columns:

```
echo "<td class='hiddos'>";
echo '<input type="text" value="'.$abc['Instanzname']. '" name="Instanzname'.$i.'"/>';
echo "</td>";
echo "<td class='hiddos'>";
echo '<input type="text" value="'.$abc['Standort_ID']. '" name="Standort_ID"'.$i.'"/>';
echo "</td>";
```

And here I am declaring the variable:

```
$Instanzname = $_POST['Instanzname' . $i . ''];
$Standort_ID = $_POST['Standort_ID' . $i . ''];
```

When I run the script, the browser gives the following error:

> Undefined index: Standort_ID1 in
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\systemübersicht\Erfassen_Server.php on line 878
>
> 1452-Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`systemuebersicht`.`hardware`, CONSTRAINT `hardware_ibfk_11` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`Standort`) REFERENCES `hardware_standort` (`Standort_ID`))

Am I overseeing something?

Comment: need more. provide more code...

Comment: I think you miss double quote in line 2 of the provided code it should be `name="Instanzname"'.$i.'"/>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is your problem, remove the `"` as below

```
echo '<input type="text" value="'.$abc['Standort_ID']. '" name="Standort_ID"'.$i.'"/>';
// error here   ---------------------------------------------------------  ^
```

Change to

```
echo '<input type="text" value="'.$abc['Standort_ID']. '" name="Standort_ID'.$i.'"/>';
```

Also in these lines, while it is not syntactically wrong you dont need the trailing `''`

```
$Instanzname = $_POST['Instanzname' . $i];

Standort_ID = $_POST['Standort_ID' . $i];
```

Answer (score 0):

This line in your code:

```
echo '<input type="text" value="'.$abc['Standort_ID']. '" name="Standort_ID"'.$i.'"/>';
```

will translate to this (assuming `$i = 1`):

```
echo '<input type="text" value="'.$abc['Standort_ID']. '" name="Standort_ID"1"/>';
```

As you can see, the name property in your input is not properly formatted.
It should work when you change it to:

```
echo '<input type="text" value="'.$abc['Standort_ID']. '" name="Standort_ID'.$i.'"/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<input type="text" value="'.$abc['Standort_ID']. '" name="Standort_ID"'.$i.'"/>';
// error here   ---------------------------------------------------------  ^

echo '<input type="text" value="'.$abc['Standort_ID']. '" name="Standort_ID'.$i.'"/>';
// correct
```